# Converting numerical expressions to lambda calculus in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Trying to make a function that converts any given numerical expression to its lambda calculus equivalent.

To do this, I've made two functions; an encode function and subst. Below are the relevant bits of my code. However, when I run my encode function, it doesn't encode multiplication expressions properly; i.e I think I've written my Add/Mul lines of code in the encode function wrong. However, I can't work out how to fix this. When I run `encode (ArithmeticNum 2)`  and `encode (SecApp (Section (ArithmeticNum 1)) (ArithmeticNum 1))` , it produces the expected output, however. Can someone help me on fixing the Add/Mul bits of the encode function so it works in all cases?

I know the multiplication syntax for encoding would look like `mul n m = \s -> \z -> n (m s) z,`
but I'm not sure how I would write this in my encode function. Could someone help me with this bit? Thanks.

```
data Lambda = LamdaApp Lambda Lambda | LambdaAbs Int Lambda | LambdaVar Int deriving (Show,Eq)

data ArithmeticExpr = Add ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr | Mul ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr | Section ArithmeticExpr | SecApp ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr | ArithmeticNum Int deriving (Show, Eq,Read)

subst :: LambdaExpr -> Int -> LambdaExpr -> LambdaExpr
subst (LambdaVar x) y e | x == y = e
subst (LambdaVar x) y e | x /= y = LambdaVar x
subst (LambdaAbs x e1) y e |  
  x /= y && not (free x e) = LambdaAbs x (subst e1 y e)
subst (LambdaAbs x e1) y e |
    x /=y && (free x e) = let x' = rename x y in
          subst (LambdaAbs x' (subst e1 x (LambdaVar x'))) y e

subst (LambdaAbs x e1) y e | x == y = LambdaAbs x e1
subst (LambdaApp e1 e2) y e = LambdaApp (subst e1 y e) (subst e2 y e)


free :: Int -> LambdaExpr -> Bool
free x (LambdaVar y) = x == y
free x (LambdaAbs y e) | x == y = False
free x (LambdaAbs y e) | x /= y = free x e
free x (LambdaApp e1 e2) = (free x e1) || (free x e2)


rename :: Int -> Int -> Int
rename x y = (max x y) + 1

encode:: ArithmeticExpr -> LambdaExpr
encode(ArithmeticNum 0) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (LambdaVar 1))
encode(ArithmeticNum n) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (helper n 0 1))
    where helper :: Int -> Int -> Int -> LambdaExpr
          helper 0 _ _ = LambdaVar 1
          helper n f x = LambdaApp (LambdaVar f) (helper (n - 1) f x)

encode (Add e1 e2) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 ( LambdaApp (LambdaApp (encode e1) (LambdaVar 0)) (LambdaApp (LambdaApp (encode e2) (LambdaVar 0)) (LambdaVar 1))))
encode (Mul e1 e2) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (LambdaAbs 2 (LambdaAbs 3 (LambdaApp (LambdaApp (LambdaVar 0) (encode e1)) (LambdaApp (LambdaVar 1) (encode e2))))))  
encode (SecApp (Section op) e1) = LambdaApp (LambdaApp (encode op) (encode e1)) (encode (ArithmeticNum 1))
encode (Section (ArithmeticNum n)) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (LambdaApp (LambdaVar 0) (encode (ArithmeticNum n))))
```

Comment: Can you clean up your code formatting? I find it very hard to read. You're also using names inconsistently, like `LamAbs` and `LambdaAbs`.

Comment: @Noughtmare Is it better now? Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: It's better, but still hard to read and inconsistent.

Comment: Not really, names are still inconsistent and there are some undefined things like `free` and `rename`. Please copy and paste a file you have just compiled in its entirety. Do not edit code on SO manually, it always ends in frustration.

Comment: @n.m. I think it should be fixed now. Sorry for the issues, I'm new to this platform so trying to get the hangs of things here.

Comment: It's ok now, but a couple of things you should take into account in the future: **1.** avoid long lines (more than ca. 90 chars) — **2.** avoid duplicating clauses or conditionals – you can have multiple guards behind a clause, and after you've checked `x/=y` there's no reason to check again `x==y` in a following guard — **3.** use whitespace to guide the eye, grouping together stuff that belongs together and seperating stuff that doesn't.

Comment: The repeated `Lambda` prefix on every constructor makes this hard to read as well. `data Expr = Application Expr Expr | Abstraction Int Expr | Var Int` would be sufficient. It's not like you need to contrast this data type with other, non-lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, multiplication in the [Church Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Calculation_with_Church_numerals) (there are other encodings) is done as follows:

```
mul n m = \s -> \z -> n (m s) z
```

Just taking this line:

```
encode (Mul e1 e2) = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (LambdaAbs 2 (LambdaAbs 3 (LambdaApp (LambdaApp (LambdaVar 0) (encode e1)) (LambdaApp (LambdaVar 1) (encode e2))))))
```

I'd say it corresponds to this in the more direct notation (assuming numbers are valid variable names):

```
mul e1 e2 = \0 -> \1 -> \2 -> \3 -> (0 e1) (1 e2)
```

So, I'd say one mistake is to have the encoded multiplication take four arguments where it should only take two. Multiplication on its own should indeed take four arguments, but in this case you are translating a multiplication that is already applied to the arguments `e1` and `e2`, so there are only two left. And the inner body of the lambda is also incorrect. You'd want this:

```
mul e1 e2 = \0 -> \1 -> e1 (e2 0) 1
```

Which is equivalant to the equation at the top of this answer.

Comment: So would `mul e1 e2 = LambdaAbs 0 (LambdaAbs 1 (encode e1) ((encode e2) LambdaVar 0) LambdaVar 1)` work or am I doing it wrong? Sorry but I'm not great with church numerals in Haskell.

Comment: @Student You do need `LambdaVar` and `LambdaApp`. Basically every space in the expression `e1 (e2 0) 1` is an infix application of `LambdaApp`. So, `0 1` would be `LambdaApp (LambdaVar 0) (LambdaVar 1)`. Also, function application associates to the left, so the fully parenthesized version would be `(e1 (e2 0)) 1`.